# autorun a program on client in LAN

Tags: networking, lan, application-server

I am doing a Project on LAN of an internet cafe. I have a scenario in which 9 nodes and a server is attached with a switch. I have a "reboot and restore" application hosted on a server. So when a client node reboots the particular application on server auto runs and restore the settings on client node.

I want to know which application server will be used for particular store and reboot application with auto start settings?

Answer (score 1):

Look, as for as Auto Star feature is concerned, You can add (to my experience) any application to the startup calls of Windows (assuming you are a windows user)....and the procedure is not that tough, 
go to start -> program -> start up ( The idea is to open this folder for you required user)
paste a shortcut of your application executable in to it..

when next time, windows will login, it will load all the applications present in this folder ( and others coming from different Registery Entries ) and thus your application will become Autostart..

and the other thing, I saw a few cafes / offices using an application named "freeze". what this application does is, it creates a snap of user settings, and each time when system is logged in, this application loads and restore that snap shop of user settings...thus, you are able to have predefined settings always applied to such scenarios as yours..

Hopes this helps..